# Unable to filter Gremlin query result conditionally

Tags: gremlin, gremlinpython

I have Gremlin query where I need to filter the result at the end. An employee id, skill name and date is passed as parameters. If the employee has that skill, only that employee id will be returned otherwise if there are other employees who reports to same manager and has that specific skill their employee id will be returned.

so if employee id 2 and C++ as skill is passed then the query will return employee id 2 only though employee id 4 also has the same skill.

If employee id 2 and Python as skill is passed though employee id 2 does not have Python skill it will return employee id 1 and 4 as they report to same manager.

I am unable to filter the end result. I am trying to check if the passed employee id exists in the result  then only return that employee id otherwise returns the entire result.

I am traversing to manager node from employee node and then finding out all other employees who reports to same manager and has the same skill as passed param. I need to traverse to manager node as I will need to implement some other checks based on attribute of manager.

My sample data can be found here https://gremlify.com/877vu2x3dfv

```
g.V().
  has('emp', 'emp_id', 2).as('empview').
  outE().
  hasLabel('emp-desig').
  has('start_date', lte(1643702400)).
  has('end_date', gte(1643702400)).
  select('empview').
  outE().
  hasLabel('emp-mgr').
  has('start_date', lte(1643702400)).
  has('end_date', gte(1643702400)).
  otherV().
  inE().
  hasLabel('emp-mgr').
  otherV().as('empidview').
  outE().
  hasLabel('emp-skill').
  otherV().
  has('skill_name', 'C++').
  select('empidview').
  coalesce(
    where(values('emp_id').is(eq(2))),
    where(values('emp_id').is(eq(2))),
    where(values('emp_id').is(neq(2)))).
  valueMap()
```

I am using the AWS Neptune database. My actual query will be written in gremlin python

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
g.V().has("emp","emp_id", 2).
  filter(outE().
         has('emp-desig','start_date', lte(1643702400)).
         has('end_date', gte(1643702400))).as('emp')
  coalesce(filter(out("emp-skill").has("skill", "skill_name", "Python")),
           outE("emp-mgr").
           has('start_date', lte(1643702400)).
           has('end_date', gte(1643702400)).
           inV().
           in("emp-mgr").
           where(is(neq("emp")))
           filter(out("emp-skill").has("skill", "skill_name", "Python")))
```

I always look for ways to eliminate heave use of the `as()/select()` patterns. Backtracking makes the query harder to read and can lead to poor performance. The approach I took should read more clearly in that you find the an employee given some criteria, then there is a simple if-then where either the employee has a skill and is returned or, otherwise, you traverse to the manager for different criteria.

Comment: Thanks @stephen. Is there any way to filter the result at the end based on employee ids found in the result set? The only  reason I did not use coalesce in the beginning is that the actual query has few more traversal which I did not specify in my query snippet. So I will not be able to filter employee ids immediately using coalesce. That's why I am traversing to manager node in the first place without using coalesce.